# Text Annotation not appearing in Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, annotation

I am trying to print a map made in an earlier version of QGIS, but now the text annotations are not appearing in the print composer.  "Draw map canvas items" is checked on.  Am I missing something else perhaps?  I've tried in both version 2.14 and 2.18 (running on a Mac with Sierra).

Here is the map in the main project window:
[image]

Here is the map in the print composer:
[image]

At this point I'm wondering if anyone else can confirm that this is just my problem and not a bug. Can anyone else on a Mac confirm that text annotations look normal in a print composer? They printed fine a year ago (the last time I worked in QGIS). I now have a new computer and downloaded the latest version of the software. I've tried creating entirely new projects to isolate the problem, but text annotations won't print in any of them.

Comment: Welcome ! Please add some more details (screenshots, qgs extracts, etc). For the moment it's quite hard to see what could go wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what "qgs extracts" are.  How do I get those?

Comment: Thank you for the detail. It's good like that. For your info, QGS are the project xml file. Screenshots will be ok :)

Comment: Nice map by the way !

Comment: If I remember correctly, map annotations are a fairly new addition to QGIS. Perhaps something has been changed in QGIS that makes map annotations created in older versions not compatible with new versions. You could test this idea by adding some new annotations and see if they show up in the print composer. If this is the problem, the solution would be either to submit a bug report and wait for a fix, or re-create all your annotations in recent version of QGIS.

Comment: How did you get those boxes around your annotation?

Comment: I've tried creating entirely new projects in the current version of QGIS with text annotation, but none show up in the print composer.  Before submitting a bug report, I'm hoping that someone else can confirm the problem (on a Mac) to rule out that it's not something quirky with my setup.

Comment: @GreyHippo -- to create the boxes around the text annotation, just double click on the annotation.  You can adjust the the background color and the frame color.

Comment: @Schaeff did you ever submit a bug report? I still can't find any further information on this problem, either.

Answer (score 2):

check "draw map canvas items" box in composer

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  As I mentioned above, it is already checked.  (I tried to screen shot that, but apparently I can only have two screenshots as a new person here.)

Comment: is the "fixed map position" box checked in the annotation properties? i unchecked it and checked it back and the annotation was gone for good in the composer

Comment: Each of the text annotations have "fixed map position" checked.  I have not unchecked them.

Comment: reading all through the comments and answers here I can't find any difference but the Mac, I'll try to get my hands on one this week

Answer (score 0):

It could maybe be related to the coordinate system. If you are using lat/long (EPSG4326 / WGS84), try using a local metric projected system and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I reprojected into NAD83, but text annotations still not appearing in the print composer.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS 3 has appeared to have fixed this issue; test out your project file with the new version and make sure it's working now as expected.